# How to declare Angular UI Modal outside of controller?

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to have my Angular Ui Modal controller/object declared outside
it's triggering controller (& in another file), without polutting the
global namespace.

Is this possible? Is it possible to declare the modal controller
like a regular controller and somehow pass parameters in (from my
trigger controller)?

I currently have: (which ain't cool)

```
(function () {
    TriggeringCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'htmlClient', 'apiCall', '$timeout', '$modal', 'utility'];
    function TriggeringCtrl($scope, htmlClient, apiCall, $timeout, $modal, utility) {

   };
  app.controller('TriggeringCtrl', TriggeringCtrl);
  var ModalCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, node, apiCall, utility) {
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have example here which is not global:
http://plnkr.co/edit/fCfvcnwP9JSHbX5L2Vuu?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $q, $timeout) {


  $scope.open = function () {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

        $scope.items = items;


        $scope.ok = function () {
          $modalInstance.close('item');
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
          $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
      },
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          var p = $q.defer(); /// simulate data
          $timeout(function(){
            p.resolve(['item1', 'item2', 'item3']);
          });
          return p.promise.then(function(data){
            return data;
          });
        }
      }
    });
  };

});
```

Comment: This is a good answer although the example is more complex than needed when it comes to working with promises. $timeout itself is promise-based so the example could be reduced to http://plnkr.co/edit/yaQpW9uyZHmo8BdIaLxt?p=preview

Comment: This hasn't allowed the modal controller to be declared in a separate file as it's being declared in the trigger controller??

Comment: @Baconbeastnz You can do also this:http://plnkr.co/edit/lI2Z8FEjZIdx6lelnqhx?p=preview

Comment: Thanks that's what I wanted. Could you change answer to that I will mark as ticked